# Chapter ranges: chapters x-y or chapter x-y?

Tags: writing-style

I am doing some proofreading using an in-house style guide and the Oxford Style Manual as references. However, I cannot find a convention regarding whether to use *chapter* or *chapter**s*** when expressing something like:

> see *chapter* 2-4

Am I not reading the Oxford Manual thoroughly enough? Is it just *chapters*? This seems obvious but I am unsure.

Comment: Just like you need to write *pp. x–y* instead of *p. x–y*.

Answer (score 2):

The - stands for *to*. Since we say *chapters 2 to 4*, we also write *chapters 2-4*.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a convention, because a reference to more than one chapter requires a plural, just as you would refer to pages 2-3 (pp. 2-3), on one hand, but to page 3 (p. 3), on the other hand.